# Invalid UTF-8 while removing "english" stopwords from a text corpus in R text mining

Tags: r, utf-8, tm

While doing text mining, I got an error removing the stopwords from a text corpus withh 500 documents in it.
I am using R 3.1.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and text mining package 0.6-1.
Here is the code, please help.

```
unsup.corpus = Corpus(DirSource(directory.location, encoding = "UTF-8"),
                      readerControl = list(language = "en_US"))


document.collection = unsup.corpus    
document.collection = tm_map(document.collection, stripWhitespace, mc.cores = 1)    
document.collection = tm_map(document.collection, content_transformer(tolower), mc.cores = 1)    
document.collection = tm_map(document.collection, removeNumbers, mc.cores = 1)    
document.collection = tm_map(document.collection, removePunctuation, mc.cores = 1)

document.collection = tm_map(document.collection, removeWords, stopwords("english"), mc.cores = 1)
```

> ###### Error
>   
>   #
>
> Error in gsub(sprintf("(*UCP)\b(%s)\b", paste(sort(words, decreasing
>   = TRUE),  :    input string 21 is invalid UTF-8

Comment: If you open the offending file in Note++(or similar functionality .txt editor) does it recognize the file as UTF-8 w/o BOM?

Comment: How sure are you that the file actually is UTF-8 encoded?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you can do is

```
document.collection = 
        tm_map(document.collection[-21], removeWords, stopwords("english"), mc.cores = 1)
```

This gets rid of the "string" with the problematic character(s).

If you want to work with the problem string independently apart from that, you can just call

```
document.collection[-21]
```

and do some investigating into the specifics.